# Someone who breeds horses

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

How a native speaker would describe someone's profession who has a breeding horse farm:

What comes to my mind:

> He has a horse breeding farm.
>
> He breeds horses.

I have no idea if they are natural. If they are not, then please let me know what shall I say here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A place where horses are bred is called a [*Stud*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stud) or occasionally [*Stud Farm*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&q=define+stud+farm).

The same word, stud, is used to describe a horse that is used for breeding.  Hence a retired racehorse would be "*Put out to stud*".

So, while your second phrase *He breeds horses* is perfectly acceptable as it describes the activity, the first phrase would be *He owns a stud*, or *He owns a stud farm*.